# Mutating Headline1 on Google Ads API

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm attempting to update Headline 1 of my Google Ads Groups. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm getting too few argument when attempting to run this

```
import argparse
import sys
from uuid import uuid4

from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.ads.googleads.errors import GoogleAdsException
from google.api_core import protobuf_helpers

ad_id= (ad id starts with 6)
# [START update_responsive_search_ad]
def update(client, customer_id, ad_id):
    ad_service = client.get_service("AdService")
    ad_operation = client.get_type("AdOperation")

    # Update ad operation.
    ad = ad_operation.update
    ad.resource_name = ad_service.ad_path(customer_id, ad_id)

    # Update some properties of the responsive search ad.
    headline_1 = client.get_type("AdTextAsset")
    headline_1.text = "hi"

    

    ad.responsive_search_ad.headlines.extend([headline_1])

    client.copy_from(
        ad_operation.update_mask, protobuf_helpers.field_mask(None, ad._pb)
    )
    # Updates the ad.
    ad_response = ad_service.mutate_ads(
        customer_id=customer_id, operations=[ad_operation]
    )
    
    print(
        f'Ad with resource name "{ad_response.results[0].resource_name}" '
        "was updated."
    )
    
update(client,customer_id,ad_id)
```

I'm attempting to try to update headline, at first I was getting no resources so I change the AD ID to AD Group ID and now I'm getting "too few"

The status code is also invalid argument:
StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT